# In-memory association reference broken: Reference parent object before save returns nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have the two following models:

```
class Seller < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cars, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :seller
end
```

Now I need to be able to reference the seller from the car, before the objects has been saved in the database, which currently doesn't work:

```
seller = Seller.new
=> #<Seller id: nil, name: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
seller.cars.build(:brand => 'Audi', :model_name => 'A4')
=> #<Car id: nil, brand: 'Audi', model_name: 'A4', created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

Now the association works from seller, but not from the car side:

```
car = seller.cars.first
=> #<Car id: nil, brand: 'Audi', model_name: 'A4', created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
car.seller
=> nil
```

How do I get the association to work properly?

PS. As stated, if I save the objects to the db, then the references work as they should.

Comment: The reason why Is way more complicated in reality, and has to do with a custom validation on what would be the 'car', where I have to call an attribute on 'seller', in order to verify that the 'car' is valid

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay I seem to have found the answer myself:

I have to specify `:inverse_of` on seller then it works:

```
class Seller < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cars, :inverse_of => :seller, :dependent => :destroy
end
```